# How initialize correctly static variable in PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android

I have  Preference class extent  PreferenceActivity.
I create `public static String quality;`  in  Preference.class i add in onCreate

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
  quality = "QUALITY_HIGH";//initialize
    }
```

and add in Preference.class this method

```
public void getQuality() {
    if (keyquality.equals("480p")) {
        quality = "QUALITY_LOW";
        //

    }
    if (keyquality.equals("720p")) {
        //
       quality = "QUALITY_720P";
    }
    if (keyquality.equals("1080p")) {
        //
        quality = "QUALITY_HIGH";
    }

}
```

in another class i create method to get my variable and set settings

```
 private void getqualityvideo() {
    /*if (Prefernce.quality == null) {
        preferencecamrecoder = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    } else {*/
        if (Prefernce.quality.equals("QUALITY_LOW")) {
            preferencecamrecoder = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
        }
        if (Prefernce.quality.equals("QUALITY_720P")) {
            preferencecamrecoder = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
        }
        if (Prefernce.quality.equals("QUALITY_HIGH")) {
            preferencecamrecoder = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        }
   // }
}
```

Problem:
when start application

```
 private void startServes() {

    btnStart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.StartService);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(mAnimationImage);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecorderService.class);

            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            startService(intent);
            changeCamera
                    .setEnabled(false);
            btnStart.setEnabled(false);
            setings.setEnabled(false);

            moveTaskToBack(false);
        }
    });

}
```

in another class in method
**getqualityvideo()** error **NullPointerException**
error in this first line
 **if (Prefernce.quality.equals("QUALITY_LOW"))** 
why the quality variable is empty?

Comment: the crash is happening when you open your application, right?

Comment: @Sujith Niraikulathan
look, crash, when i start service , but if i initialize my variable in service, application work good

Comment: can you post full logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you're setting `Preference.quality` in the `onCreate` method in your `Preference` class. So what's probably happening is that when you start your application in your other class, `Preference.quality` is going to be null because it was never initialized to anything. The reason is that the other class has no way to access the `onCreate` method in your `Preference` class as of now. `onCreate` is executed when an activity starts, but that doesn't seem to happen anywhere in your code. A solution could be to initialize `public static String quality` outside of your `onCreate` method but still within the `Preference class`,

```
public static String quality = "QUALITY_HIGH";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //insert code here
}
```

The problem was merely a scope issue.